# mysql creating rows to column

Tags: mysql

I want to convert mysql rows to column, i tried but didnt get the required output. Thankyou In Advance.
my table query is

First Table

```
CREATE TABLE `variant_to_group` (
 `variant_to_group_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `variant_group_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `variant_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`variant_to_group_ID`)
)
INSERT INTO `products_to_variants` (`products_to_variants_ID`, `variant_ID`, `variant_value`, `variant_group_ID`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'STD', 1),
(2, 1, '25', 1),
(3, 1, '50', 1),
(4, 1, '75', 1),
(5, 1, '100', 1),
(6, 2, 'USHA', 1),
(7, 2, 'SAM', 1),
(8, 2, 'Getzo', 1);
```

---

second table

```
CREATE TABLE `products_new` (
 `product_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `product_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `brand_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `categories_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `product_variant_group_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`product_ID`)
) 

INSERT INTO `products_new` (`product_ID`, `product_name`, `brand_ID`, `categories_ID`, `product_variant_group_ID`) VALUES
(1, 'Hero Honda CD 100', 1, 1, 1);
```

and the desired output required is -

```
product_name    categories_ID   variant_value_1 variant_value_2
Hero Honda CD 100   1   STD         USHA
Hero Honda CD 100   1   25          USHA
Hero Honda CD 100   1   50          USHA
Hero Honda CD 100   1   75          USHA
Hero Honda CD 100   1   100         USHA
Hero Honda CD 100   1   STD         SAM
Hero Honda CD 100   1   25          SAM
Hero Honda CD 100   1   50          SAM
Hero Honda CD 100   1   75          SAM
Hero Honda CD 100   1   100         SAM
Hero Honda CD 100   1   STD         Getzo
Hero Honda CD 100   1   25          Getzo
Hero Honda CD 100   1   50          Getzo
Hero Honda CD 100   1   75          Getzo
Hero Honda CD 100   1   100         Getzo
```

i tried some of the search result from google and stackoverflow but i failed to generated above output

Comment: You posted the create statement of the table: `variant_to_group` but the insert statement is for table: `products_to_variants`.

Comment: It is my mistake, SORRY.   this is the create table query for products_to_variant   CREATE TABLE `products_to_variants` (
  `products_to_variants_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `variant_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `variant_value` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `variant_group_ID` int(11) NOT NULL
)

Answer (score 1):

Try below query. It should produce the exact output as what you expect it would.

```
SELECT product_name,categories_ID,v1.variant_value AS "variant_value_1",
v2.variant_value  AS "variant_value_2" 
FROM products_new 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM products_to_variants WHERE variant_ID=1) v1 
ON products_new.product_id = products_new.product_variant_group_ID 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM products_to_variants WHERE variant_ID=2) v2 
ON products_new.product_id = products_new.product_variant_group_ID
ORDER BY v2.variant_value;
```

A bit explanation on the query above, I used your `products_new` table as a reference for the `LEFT JOIN`. If you look at the query I've provided, I am joining:

`products_new.product_id = products_new.product_variant_group_ID`

As far as knowing that this joining is valid or not, its up to you but I assume that it's valid. Then there are two sub-queries that I assigned with `v1` and `v2` aliases. Each of those sub-query I define value of `variant_ID` differently. As to why I use `LEFT JOIN`, it's because that your expected output require the `variant_value` column side by side differentiated by `variant_ID` value.

However, this query will only cater to your given example data and expected output. Therefore, if you have other condition(s) you would like to meet from this query, please update your question with extra information.

Comment: Thank you. This is the required output.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing @tcadidot0, As you know variant value is differentiated by variant id. at present i am having only two variant id (1,2) but it can be increase. So I want to create a Dynamic sql query to  create above result having more variants.

Comment: I am sorry, i am asking question in the comment. I update my question if you say.

Comment: Thats what I'm afraid of @Gagandeep . I'm sorry but I'm limited to just (old) MySQL 4.1 for now. Perhaps there's a way to do in later MySQL version. I can try with newer version but it will take a while. Hopefully someone will give you other suggestion soon

Answer (score 0):

you need to perform a join to get the output you are looking for

```
SELECT * FROM `products_new` 
INNER JOIN `variant_to_group`  
ON `products_new`.`variant_group_ID` = `products_new`.`product_variant_group_ID`;
```